# Want to hold a package from upgrading. Don't work

Tags: debian, apt-get

I'm having a xen box which runs squeeze.

the `linux-image-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem` never upgrades properly and I want to stop it from upgrading any more. It's annoying that it tries and fails every time I run `apt-get`.

I issued

```
echo "linux-image-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem hold" | dpkg --set-selections
echo "linux-image-686-bigmem hold" | dpkg --set-selections
```

and I get

```
root@y:/etc# dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
linux-image-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem                 hold
linux-image-686-bigmem                          hold
```

But it still tries to upgrade

```
root@y:/etc# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up linux-image-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem (2.6.32-31) ...
```

and fails.

I got below reply with `dpkg -l linux-image-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
hF  linux-image-2. 2.6.32-31      Linux 2.6.32 for PCs with 4GB+ RAM
```

It's hF, not hi.

Comment: did you try apt-get update after you issued the hold command?

Comment: @Journeyman yes, I did apt-get update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hold kernels on my servers all the time, so I know it works in general. The "1 not fully installed or removed" worries me. My `dpkg -l linux-image-2.6.26-2-686-bigmem` (on lenny) shows:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Hold/Reinst-required/X=both-problems (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
hi  linux-image-2. 2.6.26-25lenny Linux 2.6.26 image on PPro/Celeron/PII/PIII/
```

with an `hi` at the beginning. I'm guessing yours shows something else?

Comment: Please see the modified question.  It's hF, not hi. So, what can I do then and what does it means?

Comment: "F" is "failed configuration" -- I assume there's something else on screen when it tries to install and fails? If not, you can try `apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem` and see if that either makes the errors more clear, or finally configures itself properly.

Comment: I know I can't get it successfully installed and there are errors when installing. But all I want is stop it from installing any more. Can that be done?

Comment: My guess is you'll have to try installing a different kernel version, then removing the problematic one. I doubt 'hold' was intended to prevent a failing package from attempting a reinstall, but only to prevent version upgrades on a completely installed package. The only other option you have is to find out why it's failing to install, and fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **Synaptic>Package>Lock version.**

The other option is one I can across called apt-pinning. [Here's a tutorial on it](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html).